# how do i give gradient color for border outline

Tags: flutter, dart

```
child: TextField(
        style: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.blue
        ),
        autofocus: autoFocus,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        controller: controller,
        maxLength: 1,
        cursorColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,

        decoration:  InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
            ),
            counterText: '',
            hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20.0)),

        onChanged: (value) {
          if (value.length == 1) {
            FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
          }
        },
      ),
```

Comment: edit your question. what to you want? what did you try? you will not get "free" anwsers

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use gradient_textfields package in flutter.You can make it attractive than the normal textfields

```
$ flutter pub add gradient_textfield
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Create a custom implementation

There is no way to provide a gradient to the existing `OutlineInputBorder` or `UnderlineInputBorder` classes. However, it is possible to create a implementation for this.

- One possibility is to create a entirely custom implementation extending the abstract class `InputBorder` and implementing the member functions. Both `OutlineInputBorder` and `UnderlineInputBorder` extends `InputBorder`.
- Another simpler possibility is to extend either `OutlineInputBorder` or `UnderlineInputBorder`, and simply apply a shader to the `Paint` used.

#### Pseudocode for second approach

- To do this you need to override the paint method, base it on the implementation in the parent class.
- Since some methods are private in `OutlineInputBorder`, you need to copy them over.
- Do note Material is a part of Flutter and the code is governed by a BSD license, so it should be legal to copy the code from the parent class if you do so while fulfilling the license conditions.

I have intentionally left out some parts, so you need to fill out the blanks.

```dart
class GradientOutlineInputBorder extends OutlineInputBorder {

  const GradientOutlineInputBorder({
    super.borderSide = const BorderSide(),
    super.borderRadius = const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4.0)),
    super.gapPadding = 4.0,
  });

  // We are interested in overriding the paint method to apply a shader to 
  // the Paint object. You should see the parent implementation and copy 
  // what you need into this.
  @override
  void paint(
      Canvas canvas,
      Rect rect, {
        double? gapStart,
        double gapExtent = 0.0,
        double gapPercentage = 0.0,
        TextDirection? textDirection,
      }) {
    // ... consider adding the asserts from the parent.

    final Paint paint = borderSide.toPaint();

    // This is how you could add a gradient.
    paint.shader = LinearGradient(
      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
      end: Alignment.bottomRight,
      colors: [
        Colors.grey,
        Colors.yellow,
      ],
    ).createShader(rect);

    // ... add code for drawing to the canvas. 
    // Take a look at how this is done in the parent class, and consider 
    // copying over the methods _cornersAreCircular and _gapBorderPath.
  }
}
```

## Proof it is possible

[image: Proof it is possible]